# C# running a exe and waiting for it to close

Tags: c#, windows

Hoping you can help me with the code below, when a user logs into a certain PC the program below runs. After the process the runs the exe closes I want the PC to logoff, the myProcess_Exited method below doesn't run, can you spot any problems?

Thanks
Steven

```
private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
         System.Diagnostics.Process proc1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
         proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\windows\\SysWOW64\\shutdown.exe";
         proc1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/l";
         proc1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
         proc1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
         proc1.Start();
         Application.Exit();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
             System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo p = new                                            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"K:\App\pc\stub.exe");
             p.Arguments = "-RunForever";
             proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
             proc.StartInfo = p;
             proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
             proc.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
             proc.Start();
 }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo: proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\windows\\SysWOW64\\shutdown.exe"; Should be proc1.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\windows\\SysWOW64\\shutdown.exe";

Comment: You should not refer to C:\windows as the user may have the system installed on another drive. Use the method Environment.GetFolderPath(...) instead. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below one works perfectly fine.

```
    Process proc = new Process();

    private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc1.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\windows\\SysWOW64\\shutdown.exe";
        proc1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/l";
        proc1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        proc1.Start();
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo p = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"K:\App\pc\stub.exe");
        p.Arguments = "-RunForever";
        Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = p;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
        proc.Start();
    }
```

Comment: I have it working, the code was fine it was another problem with the form.